# How to Get selected Toggle Button and Match them with Random Number in Android app

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, togglebutton

My Code is here
Please help to get this 
I am making a App where user select some togglebuttons and then click play button

what happen Application record all the toggleButton id and when user click play button App generates a random number and then match it to selected number if it got matched then user wins...

Total number of Toggle button set to 12 in the game

Please Help

how can i get selected toggleButtons ids and how to match them with random numbers please help

Main.java

```
package com.authorwjf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<ToggleButton> mToggleButtons = new ArrayList<ToggleButton>();
    TextView textView1, textView2;
    Button button1;
    ToggleButton t;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ToggleButton cb = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            cb = new ToggleButton(this);
            cb.setText(Integer.toString(i));
            cb.setTextOn(Integer.toString(i));
            cb.setTextOff(Integer.toString(i));
            cb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
            cb.setOnClickListener(this);
            cb.setId(i);
            registerForContextMenu(cb);
            mToggleButtons.add(cb);
        }

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(mToggleButtons));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        t = (ToggleButton) v;
            if (t.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), t.getText() + " Enable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), t.getText() + " Disable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.authorwjf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ToggleButton> mToggleButtons = null;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<ToggleButton> b) 
    {
        mToggleButtons = b;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mToggleButtons.size();
    }

    @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (Object) mToggleButtons.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //in our case position and id are synonymous
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ToggleButton ToggleButton;
        if (convertView == null) {
            ToggleButton = mToggleButtons.get(position);
        } else {
            ToggleButton = (ToggleButton) convertView;
        }
        return ToggleButton;
        }

    }
```

Please Help stackies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click listener for the button, there you should be able to get IDs of the toggleButtons that has been checked at the moment of the pressing of the button:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            ToggleButton cb = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                cb = new ToggleButton(this);
                cb.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                cb.setTextOn(Integer.toString(i));
                cb.setTextOff(Integer.toString(i));
                cb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
                cb.setOnClickListener(this);
                cb.setId(i);
                registerForContextMenu(cb);
                mToggleButtons.add(cb);
            }

            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(mToggleButtons));
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                }
            });

            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

                 int random = (new Random()).nextInt(12);

                 ArrayList<Integer> positive_IDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 for(int i = 0; i < mToggleButtons; i++){
                     ToggleButton b = mToggleButtons.get(i);
                     if(b.isChecked()){
                    positive_IDs.add(b.getId());    
                     } 
                 }

                 // do whatever needed with the positive_IDs, for example:

                 if(positive_IDs.contains(random)){
                     // doAction();
                 }       
          }
           });


        }
```

Comment: thanks man,,, how can i match that if the ramdom number that i have generated on click is inside this array or not

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean.. Do you want to assign random numbers to something?

Comment: I have a int value.. I want to find out that is it in the positive_IDs... Please Help

Comment: @Sam I edited the code, added a random number, and checked if it's included in the arraylist of positive_IDs. If it answers your question, please accept the answer to close it.